# Reactjs - Props Is Lost While Using It In A Child Component TypeError:

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I have the following code in react passes props from stateless component to state-full one and I get TypeError while running.
However, when I use props with same name the error goes away!
Your help would be appreciated in advance

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    class App extends Component {
        state = {
           title:'xxxxxxx', 
           show:true,
           SampleData:[object, object]
        }
      render() {

    const {SampleData} = this.state.SampleData
        return (
          <div>
    <SampleStateless list = {SampleData}/>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    export default App;




const SampleStateless = (props) => {
  const {list} = props
  return (
    <div>
       <SampleStatefullComponent secondlist = {list}    />
    </div>
  );
}


class SampleStatefullComponent extends Component {
  state = {
    something:''
  }

  render () {
    const {secondlist} = this.props
    console.log(secondlist);
    // I get data correctly in console

    const items = secondlist.map (item => return {some js}) 
    //TypeError: secondlist is undefined
    return (
      <div>
        {items}
      </div>
    )
 }
}
```

Comment: Because your SampleData is a string but not an array for map to work

Comment: `const {SampleData} = this.state.SampleData` should be `const {SampleData} = this.state`. Also `Array.map` primitive only works on Arrays, not strings.

Comment: I have tried with array of objects. The result is the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing map on a string but map works only on arrays. Take a look at corrected code

Also should be

```
const {SampleData} = this.state;
```

but not

```
const {SampleData} = this.state.SampleData;
```

Updated code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
        class App extends Component {
            state = {
               title:'xxxxxxx', 
               show:true,
               SampleData:[{'id': "01", "name": "abc"}, {'id': "02", "name": "xyz"}]
            }
          render() {

        const {SampleData} = this.state;
            return (
              <div>
        <SampleStateless list = {SampleData}/>
              </div>
            );
          }
        }

        export default App;




    const SampleStateless = (props) => {
      const {list} = props
      return (
        <div>
           <SampleStatefullComponent secondlist = {list}    />
        </div>
      );
    }


    class SampleStatefullComponent extends Component {
      state = {
        something:''
      }

      render () {
        const {secondlist} = this.props
        console.log(secondlist);
        // I get data correctly in console

           const items  = {secondlist && secondlist.map (item => item.name)}

        return (
          <div>
            {items}
          </div>
        )
     }
    }
```

Comment: before I do map action the props ( secondlist ) is lost ( will be undefined). problem is not related to map

Comment: Where it's undefined? The secondList is never undefined here because it is an array initialized with objects. I tested in my local it always the data but not undefined. Have you tried my answer?

Comment: What is the meaning of "{secondlist && secondlist.map (item => item.name)}" in your code?

Comment: That is conditional check that checks for whether secondlist is undefined or not. In your case its not required

Comment: Why did you change a code again while previous one was working? Now it does not work so

Comment: I get “TypeError: secondlist is undefined”

Comment: Ok then you need to add this condition check {secondlist && secondlist.map (item => item.name)}. I updated my answer again

Comment: Thank you. However I did not understand why this problem is presented? I get corrected data in console log while they are lost after that

Comment: The condition check allows only when secondlist has data. that's natural behavior in react when props are received from parent. secondlist is undefined until it receives data from parent

Comment: It receives data as you see in the log. Data is lost after receiving! Why?

Comment: I verified in my system. It works const items  = secondlist.map (item => item.name); fine without conditional check. The secondlist print always data because the SampleData that you pass to child and child is already pre initialized with data so it will never be undefined. Not sure why it's happening for you. You must be doing something wrong

Comment: Does it appear because of passing props from an stateless to a class component?